# Indexing in numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am trying various ways for slicing a numpy arrray. I thought that both the print statements will yield the same output. But they are not. Can anyone explain me why?

```
import numpy as np
two_dim_array = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
print(two_dim_array)
print(two_dim_array[[0,1],[2,3]]) #-----> why wont this work?
print(two_dim_array[:2,[2,3]])   #-----> why would this work?
```

Comment: Slices and lists index in different ways.  Do spend time reading the numpy indexing docs.  It will save time later.

Comment: Its the difference in advance and basic indexing, you can find details [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html). I have tried to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: When the index contains 2 or more arrays (or lists that can be made into arrays), their interaction is defined by `broadcasting`.  In your example you have shape (2,) and (2,) arrays resulting in a (2,) selection.  The first needs to be (1,2) shaped if you want a (2,2) result.

Answer (score 2):

#### Basic vs Advance indexing

To understand this behavior, you may want to understand how basic indexing and advance indexing [works](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in numpy.

**Basic indexing** results in views, while **advance indexing** results in a copy.

**Advance indexing** can be combined with **basic indexing** but the way they behave is completely different. **Basic indexing** occurs when the object used for indexing is -

- A slice object that is of the form start:stop:step
- An integer
- Or a tuple of slice objects and integers

**Advance indexing** is triggered when -

- An ndarray of type integer or Boolean
- A tuple with at least one sequence object
- Is a non tuple sequence object

#### How they work

If you are working for indexes for multiple axes, **advanced indexes** (with arrays/lists) always are broadcast and iterated as one, while **basic indexing** (with slices) acts like repeated application of slicing over the axes.

1. This means that when using **basic indexing** as `arr[slice(0,3), slice(3,5)]`, you are taking a view of the first rows *and then* the 3rd and 4th column of the array.
2. But when using **advance indexing** as `arr[[0,2],[3,4]]`, you are taking the `(0,3)` *and then* the `(2,4)` indexed over both axis at once using broadcasting.

In your case, you are mixing basic and advance indexing. Let's first define the indexing objects and then play with them a bit to understand what's happening -

```
import numpy as np

two_dim_array = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])

rows = [0,1]
cols = [2,3]
row_slice = slice(0,2) #same as 0:2, or :2
```

In the first case, let's use basic indexing on `axis=0` and advance indexing on `axis=1`. Here the advance indexing for the 2 columns is performed first and then copies of the subspace rows are fetched through basic indexing.

```
two_dim_array[row_slice, cols]
```

```
array([[3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```

In second case, lets use advance indexing on both axes. This fetches copies of the array by iterating over both the rows and cols arrays/lists at once.

```
two_dim_array[rows, cols]
```

```
array([3, 8])    #(0,2) and (1,3) elements
```

But, as I mentioned, these indexes are broadcasted. Therefore, if you want to achieve the same result from advance indexing as you are with basic indexing, you can use something like `np.ix_`

```
obj = np.ix_(rows, cols)
obj
```

```
(array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[2, 3]]))
```

This creates 2 arrays in such a way that when broadcasted, result in (0,2), (0,3), (1,2), (1,3) indexes.

```
two_dim_array[obj]
```

```
array([[3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```

Hope that clarifies how this works!