# In numpy, is there a function to find the inverse of ix_?

Tags: numpy

With `numpy`, my goal is to select a quadratic submatrix from a quadratic matrix, and then also look at the collection of elements that are not in the first submatrix.

For the first submatrix, I'm using `np.ix_`:

```py
import numpy as np
r = np.random.rand(3,3)
l = [1,2]
r[np.ix_(l, l)]
```

Then, `r[np.ix_(l, l)]` will pick out a 2x2 matrix, marked by `**`:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | r0,0 | r0,1 | r0,2 |
| 1 | r1,0 | ** r1,1 ** | ** r1,2** |
| 2 | r2,0 | ** r2,1 ** | ** r2,2 ** |

But now what is the best approach to select the difference between the submatrix and the parent matrix?

I have looked at:

- `~np.ix_`, like `~np.eye`, but this doesn't seem to be supported
- `np.subtract`, but the problem is that I need to select the elements by their indices and not by their values.

Comment: `r[l,l]` will get you what you want. as i elaborate below

Comment: Those 'remaining' elements don't form an array.  In ypur example it's an L shape, in another it could be an array with a hole.  You could make a boolean mask that is True in the hole and False else where (or its inverse) and use that to select the not_in_ix values, or make a masked array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment by @hpaulj, I followed the approach with the `numpy.ma` submodule:

```py
import numpy as np
r = np.random.rand(3,3)
l = [1,2]
r[np.ix_(l, l)]

import numpy.ma as ma
mask = ma.zeros(r.shape)
mask[np.ix_(l, l)] = 1
```

Then, `ma.compressed()` gives the desired result:

`ma.compressed(ma.array(r, mask=mask))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.ix_` is equivalent to using basic indexing, but by triggering advanced indexing.

So it lets you **fetch all the elements belonging to the 1st and 2nd rows and 1st and 2nd columns** completely as a copy (basic indexing yields a view)

```
import numpy as np
r = np.random.rand(3,3)
l = [1,2]
r[np.ix_(l, l)]
```

```
array([[0.46899841, 0.49051596],
       [0.00256912, 0.86447371]])
```

Equivalent to `np.ix_`, using basic indexing (this is a view and not a copy!) -

```
r[1:3, 1:3]
```

```
array([[0.46899841, 0.49051596],
       [0.00256912, 0.86447371]])
```

If you, however, want to **fetch the (1,1) and (2,2) index elements**, then you can directly use advance indexing as below -

```
r[l,l]
```

```
array([0.46899841, 0.86447371])
```

As you can see, this returns the diagonal elements which you are looking for (with the `np.eye` for example)

Read more about how indexing (basic and advance) works [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) or check out a detailed answer where I explain this as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66391350/4755954).

Comment: Thank you for the additional info on indexing, but I fear my question was a little unclear. I'm not looking for the entries r1,1 and r2,2 elements, but rather for r0,0, r0,1, r0,2, r1,0, r2,0. I.e. all the values that have not been picked out by `np.ix_`.

Comment: why not use `r[:3, :3]`? Would that work for you? Just to understand, which one is your parent matrix and which is your sub matrix?

Comment: Using slices in indexing eg. `0:3` or `1:3` will allow you to fetch a VIEW from the original parent matrix and you can make updates to this view, which will also update the values in the parent matrix. However, if you use `np.ix_` you will end up creating a copy. Doing operations over the copy will not be able to assign values back to the parent.